# getting dropdown value from drupal

Tags: php, drupal-7

I want to get selected dropdown value in my common_utilities.module. How can i get it?
I am using `$form_state['values']['field_please_select_type_of_enqu']['und'],`
But this is printing "array". Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Use krp or print_r function to debug your value.

Comment: try dpm($form_state['values']['field_please_select_type_of_enqu']['und']); to see what's in there.